# MySQL equivalent to MSSQL Geography functions

Tags: mysql, geospatial

I couldn't find anything on this, hence the new thread.
We have an application where the data is stored in SQL Server. Some tables have columns of the type "Geography". We use the SQL-Server function STDistance to filter out data within a specified distance. Now we are researching a little on converting the application to PHP for different reasons. One of the heaviest reasons is the cost of ASP.Net and SQL-Server. Now i can't seem to find anything on how MySQL handles Geography-datatype, am i right it doesn't exist?

Isn't it possible to create own functions in MySQL? I thought i could create simple function that calculates whether a location is within the desired radius. What would be the most efficient way of doing this? Of course i could calculate for each row if the coordinates is within the radius, but that feels inefficient and not like a very scalable solution. I was thinking that i first would select all the rows where **x1>lat>x2** and **y1>lon>y2** and then do the "heavy calculation".

What would be the best way of doing this?

Comment: [MySQL spatial extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/spatial-extensions.html) but they are not as advanced as SQL-Server or Postgres spatial features.

Comment: Yep, MySQL is certainly weak at this point. Even the spatial extensions are only good for 'flat' coordinates last time I looked, so no good for lat/lon coords on say, for instance, earth...

Comment: Thank you for your points! I didn't know PostgreSQL had support for geospatial data, will have to look into that :)

Comment: You get what you pay for when using MySQL